# Assign value to multiple column combo box in VBA access

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I set a combo box `column count=2` and the combo box `column width="0;1"` i set one `column width=0` because i need to hide this column. when i assign a value to the combo box for example `combo Box="12`"  but this value is in the first column.So i want to assign it to the second column but how?

Answer (score 2):

Set its property at *Data, BoundColumn* to: 2

Or reverse the columns and hide the last column.

Answer (score 0):

It is the boundcolumn property that decides what will be stored in the value property and corresponding column number. Make sure you have boundcolumn=2 for above your requirement of 0 width first column, assign combo value to second column

Comment: But the problem is about i don't how to assign combo value to second column!! May you please show me the syntax ??

Comment: <control name>.value = [desired value] this is the syntax for assigning value to control. The list values are used only to display, and not assign. It is control source property that decides which field in the table will be assigned the value of assigned value property. You want to associate the second column to the value of combo, for this you just need to change boundcolumn=2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hiding the first column anyway...why not just get rid of it to begin with.  Then you'll have one column and that combo box will bound to that one by default.